# JNI not found my other activityy

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

i have a application on java + c++.

IDE is - visual studio with android plugin.

i have 2 activity : 1-nativeActivity , 2- activity on java.

activity on java is main. 
after java activity i start nativeactivity. in java activity there are a purchase manager. i want call to him from a native activity.

```
<activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" android:name="android.app.NativeActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent">
  <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="main" />
</activity>

<activity android:name="BillingActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

in onCreate BillingActivity i start nativeActivity.
in native activity i do

```
    jclass billing = env->FindClass("Lcom/crystalreality/crystaltv/BillingActivity;");
```

but i have

```
    jclass billing = env->FindClass("Lcom/crystalreality/crystaltv/BillingActivity;");
    05-20 16:40:55.061: W/System.err(28592): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lcom/crystalreality/crystaltv/BillingActivity;
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#faq_FindClass

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you don't need the "L" at the beginning (and ";" at the end) of your class sig.

```
jclass billing = env->FindClass("com/crystalreality/crystaltv/BillingActivity");
```

You should only need L...; form sigs if you're looking for an array class. That's my understanding from [these lines](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#faq_FindClass) of documentation.

Failing that, have you used any obfuscation java-side?

Comment: without obfuscation. standart building of application. i try your variant? but no changes.

Comment: Exactly the same stack trace?

Comment: if i code code with 'L...' before printing stacktrace i have '... dvmClassLoader rejecting Lcom/....'  . stacktraces is equals.

Comment: Ah ok. Are you doing anything non-standard with class loaders, or specifically set a value in the manifest to something non-default?

Comment: no. i dont do anything with classloader. a big part of manifest there is in a topic. other:   <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:debuggable="true" android:hasCode="true" android:label="@string/app_name">

Comment: Yeah- I was wondering if you hadn't updated manifest when introducing java. Have to admit this is all I know- other than that if you're on  a different thread or something you can end up unable to traverse to the class loader. We tend to use handlers back in Java. I'd strongly recommend trying the bulleted points in the documentation above- such as cacheing in JNI_OnLoad. And good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The correct usage of FindClass is something like this:

```
env->FindClass("com/crystalreality/crystaltv/BillingActivity");
```